# Що таке "удти" у пісні "Ой не удти вітер віє"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Що таке "удти" у пісні "[Ой не удти вітер віє](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8UlTo2ocZc)"?

> Ой не **удти** вітер віє уткі мені треба,
> Виглядаю миленькую з пуд чужого неба.
> Кажуть зорьки,кажуть ясні де вна пребиває,
> Серце хоче вість подати а куди не знає.

Мені здається, це може бути слово з якогось діалекту. Навряд чи це друкарська помилка, тому що слово використовується і в назві пісні.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> <sub>[Іван Панькевич](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [*Українські говори Підкарпатської Руси і сумежних областей. Частина І. Звучня і морфологія*](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/pankevych-i-ukrayinski-govory-pidkarpatskoyi-rusy-i-sumezhnyh-oblastej-chastyna-i-zvuchnya-i-morfologiya/)</sub>
>
> [Звук **u**](https://diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/19764/file.pdf#page=127)
>
> В прийменнику **одъ*: *удда́ти* — можешся *уддати*, за кого хочеш<sup>1</sup>, сьім раз бӧльшоє *уд* сих дерев<sup>2, 3</sup>, пак звідалися *уд* нього<sup>4</sup>, *уд* цього<sup>5</sup>, *уставай ут* стола *ут* свого<sup>6</sup>, і *уд* того стали жиды пістриговаті<sup>7</sup>, та *у́дкы* вы гроши набрали<sup>8</sup>, журюся, як ***у́дти*** ізыйти<sup>9</sup>, кидь доўжен гроші, а оби *уддаў*<sup>10</sup>, так *удмолод*<sup>11</sup>, вітер завійав *уд* мени<sup>12</sup>, оби му борода *утпала*<sup>13</sup>, *у́тті* треба принести воду<sup>14</sup>, а языкы *поудрізовав*<sup>15</sup>, тыма ключами *поудмыкав*<sup>16</sup>, айбо вӧн не годен быў (буў) *удговоритися*,<sup>17</sup> та обӧбраўся, ож вӧн достане царськӧ(в) донцьі *уд* левицьі молока<sup>18</sup>, тот далеко уттӧдь *видить*<sup>19</sup>, *у́дтӧдь* пӧшла пуд теллицю<sup>20</sup>. Мої записи: *|ûtcʼi* (Заріча), *|ûtty |ûtkʼi*, *|ûttüdʼ* (Осой)<sup>21</sup>.
>
> 1. Пузняковці, Верх. Зн. I, 143
> 2. тамже Верхр. Зн. I. 135
> 3. Замічу однак, що Пузняковці належать до говору перехідного, де побіч рефлексу *ü* (у Верхр. *ö*) виступає рефлекс *u*
> 4. Дунковиця, Верх. Зн. I, 145
> 5. Солочин, Гн. Е. З. IV. 33
> 6. Стройна, Гн. Е. З. IV, 56
> 7. В. Раковець, Верх. Зн. I, 147
> 8. Дуновиця, Верх. Зн. I, 145
> 9. Ільниця, Верх. Зн. I, 148
> 10. Луково, Гн. Е. З. IV, 70
> 11. Луково, Гн. Е. 3. IV, 73
> 12. Кушниця, Гн. Е. З. IV, 88
> 13. Кушниця, Гн. Е. 3. IV, 91
> 14. Вучково, Гн. Е. 3. IV, 76
> 15. Страбичово, Верх. Зн. I, 130
> 16. тамже, Верх. Зн. I, 130
> 17. В Шард, Верх. Зн. I, 151
> 18. тамже В. Зн. I, 158
> 19. тамже Верх. Зн. I, 153
> 20. тамже В. Зн. I, 154
> 21. [коментарь во̂д себе] тут *|* означаїть наголос.

З назви книги зрозуміло, що то закарпатські і суміжні говори. За державним записом (*од* > *вод* > *від*) це [*відти*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=14006&page=453): те саме, що *зві́дти*. Перехід *о* > *у* досить поширений, затвердив ся і в державній мові: *поробок* > *парубок*, *яблоко* > *яблуко*; можуть існувати парабіжно *-ова-* (*друк-ова-ний*) > *-ува-* (*друк-ува-ти*); ітд, тому в правописах для його існують окремі правила.

Також раџу звернути увагу на тутешнє запитаннє [*Префікси і прийменники од- і від-*](/q/7127/585), звідки і візьму мапу:

<sup>[*Атлас української мови*, т. 2](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0002502), к. 251</sup>
[image]